# How do you cancel a previous 'running' spinnaker execution when starting a new execution

Tags: spinnaker

We have a pipeline in Spinnaker that asks for manual judgement.

There is the possible scenario that developers push a new build, but it does not proceed as the existing pipeline (Waiting for the manual judgement) is still running. We would like a way to have this older execution get cancelled when the newer one is created.

There is the option of allowing multiple concurrent executions, but then it's possible that the developers will click the judgement step for the wrong one.

How would you go about either cancelling existing running executions on a new run (You can only cancel older queued ones using documented options available in the GUI), or including a stage in your pipeline that first looks for and cancels existing running executions.

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this within Spinnaker stages?

Answer (score 0):

Query for the particular pipelineconfigid and check if there are any running executions

```
/executions?pipelineConfigIds=&limit=&statuses=
```

Find the execution id and use the below api to cancel it:

```
/pipelines/{id}/cancel
```

Reference: 
[getLatestExecutionsByConfigIdsUsingGET](https://www.spinnaker.io/reference/api/docs.html#api-Executionscontroller-getLatestExecutionsByConfigIdsUsingGET)

[cancelPipelineUsingPUT1](https://www.spinnaker.io/reference/api/docs.html#api-Pipelinecontroller-cancelPipelineUsingPUT1)

Comment: But how do I do that from within a spinnaker pipeline stage? I'd rather not resort to having to spin up Jenkins to do this (I have seen some recommendation to do this), it seems rather janky.

It would be nice if there was a way for spinnaker to manipulate itself without relying on 3rd party tooling.

Comment: I haven’t tried this but I think you should be able to use multiple webhook stages to get this done. have used the web hook stage to call API’s, you should be able to process the output and assign it to variables.